# Dockerコンテナで既存アプリを起動しましたが投稿がうまくいかず、画像が表示できません。

Tags: docker, amazon-s3

#### 環境

ruby 2.6.5
rails 6
MySQL
M1チップ搭載macOS

#### 解決したいこと

Dockerコンテナで既存アプリを起動しましたが投稿がうまくいかず、画像が表示できません。
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_REGION
をdocker-compose.ymlに記述しましたが、エラーになりました。

secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
secret_access_key='AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
secret_access_key : ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
色々書き方を試しましたが未だにうまくいきません。
わかる方がいらしたら教えてください！
よろしくお願いします。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```
Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError in Items#index

Showing /fridge_app/app/views/items/_item.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: 
missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options:
 - :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
 - :credentials
 - :credentials_provider
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当するソースコード

**Dockerfile**

```docker
FROM ruby:2.6.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https wget && \
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
RUN mkdir /fridge_app
WORKDIR /fridge_app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /fridge_app/
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.1.4
RUN gem update --system \
    && gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION \
    && bundle install -j 4
COPY . /fridge_app

RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN bundle exec rails webpacker:install

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/src/bin

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    platform: linux/x86_64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      region: ap-northeast-1
      access_key_id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/fridge_app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError` は環境変数などで AWS のクレデンシャルが与えられていないときに出るエラーです。

おそらくローカルで動かす際は環境変数もしくは `~/.aws/credentials` に設定がされており動いていたものが、コンテナの上で動かす際は一切設定されていないのでエラーとなったのではないでしょうか。

`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` と `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` を適切に取得し、`AWS_REGION` と共に設定するようにしてみてください。この際 `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` は秘匿値であることにご注意ください。

更に、もしこの後このアプリを AWS 上で動かすのであれば、IAM Role をアタッチしてクレデンシャルを生の値では扱わないのがお勧めです。

公式ドキュメントはこちらです: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html

Comment: コメントありがうございます
環境変数の設定をやってみましたが、エラーが解消されませんでした。
お知恵を拝借できると幸いです。

Comment: docker-compose.yml を見る限り、変数の受け渡しに失敗しています。ドキュメントを読んでみてください。

Comment: ドキュメント読みましたが、未だに苦戦してます。
書き方の問題でしょうか？アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

Comment: たぶん `~/.aws/credentials` で指定する場合と環境変数で指定する場合を混同なさっています。今やっているのは後者です。これを docker-compose.yml で行うには https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers のようにします。なのでたとえば `- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ほにゃらら` のような書き方になります。

Comment: とりあえず暗号を直書きしたら画像も投稿できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: .envファイルで宣言して環境変数展開してうまくいきました。本当にありがとうございました。